# In vim, how do I create a command which remembers the word under the cursor?

Tags: c++, regex, vim

I'm currently working on some C++ code which defines many things via macros and I've figured out the following regex which is working quite well in including these macros when looking for symbol definitions:

```
egrep -nrw --include=*.{c,h,i}{pp,xx} '^ *((struct|class|using|namespace) |typedef.*|[A-Z][_A-Z]*.)Symbol' .
```

I am trying to map Ctrl+F to this command in vim, and currently have the following:

```
map <C-F> :tabnew<CR>:redraw!<CR>:r! egrep -nrw --include=*.{c,h,i}{pp,xx} '^ *((struct<bar>class<bar>using<bar>namespace) <bar>typedef.*<bar>[A-Z][_A-Z]*.)Symbol' .
```

This works, but it'd be great to automatically replace `Symbol` with the word under the cursor when I press Ctrl+F. My best guess is to replace `Symbol` with `<C-r><C-w>`, but this appears to fail because the previous commands take cursor away from the symbol I wanted to find.

How do I get vim to remember `<C-r><C-w>` so that I can insert it later?

(Also, I'm guessing this approach could use some refining. I've seen a special window showing compiler errors before which opened as a split buffer and when I hit enter it jumped to that location. Something like that would be very helpful too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<expr>` mappings for this.  This allows you to bind keys to the output of a function.  When combining this with @Zach's answer, this should do what you want:

```
map <expr> <C-F> ":tabnew<CR>:redraw!<CR>:r! egrep -nrw --include=*.{c,h,i}{pp,xx} '^ *((struct<bar>class<bar>using<bar>namespace) <bar>typedef.*<bar>[A-Z][_A-Z]*.)" . expand("<cword>") . "' ."
```

Relevent help topics:

```
:help :map-<expr>
:help matchstr()
:help getline()
:help col()
```

Comment: Almost there, that successfully gets the /character/ under the cursor, but when I say /symbol/ I was actually talking about a whole word. E.g. if my cursor is between the `(` and `)` in `we often use foob(a)r in examples`, then I'd like `foobar` to be inserted, not `a`. Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: I got it! I'm using `expand('<cword>')` instead of `matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.')`. Could you edit your answer and I'll accept it? I'm also editing the question to say 'word' instead of 'symbol'.